# Custom allocator fails to rebind to Other type

Tags: c++, templates, stl, allocator

All

I have code for my custom allocator that is written with intent to be a proxy for other allocators to be able for example to gather allocation statistics or whatever else

```
 template<int Id, class T, class BaseAlloc> 
class SelfTracingAllocator
    : public BaseAlloc
{
typedef AllocationStatistics<Id> StatsType;

public:
    typedef typename BaseAlloc              base;
    typedef typename base::raw_pointer      raw_pointer;
    typedef typename base::pointer          pointer;
    typedef typename base::const_pointer    const_pointer;
    typedef typename base::reference        reference;
    typedef typename base::const_reference  const_reference;
    typedef typename base::size_type        size_type;
    typedef typename base::value_type       value_type;
    typedef typename base::difference_type  difference_type;

    template<typename Other>
    struct rebind
    {
        typedef SelfTracingAllocator<Id, Other, base> other;
    };

    SelfTracingAllocator()
    {
    }

    SelfTracingAllocator( const SelfTracingAllocator& rhs )
    {
    }

    template<typename Other>
    inline SelfTracingAllocator( const SelfTracingAllocator<Id, Other, base>& rhs )
    {
    }

    ~SelfTracingAllocator()
    {
    }

    template<typename Other>
    inline SelfTracingAllocator& operator=( const SelfTracingAllocator<Id, Other, base>& rhs )
    {
        return (*this);
    }

    inline raw_pointer allocate(size_type count, const void* ptr)
    {
        StatsType::allocated_ += count * sizeof(value_type);
        return base::allocate(count, ptr);
    }

    inline raw_pointer allocate(size_type count)
    {
        StatsType::allocated_ += count * sizeof(value_type);
        return base::allocate(count);
    }

    inline void deallocate( pointer ptr, size_type count )
    {
       StatsType::deallocated_ += count * sizeof(value_type);
       return base::deallocate(ptr, count);
    }

};

template<class T, class U, int Id, class BaseAlloc>
inline bool operator==(const SelfTracingAllocator<Id, T, BaseAlloc>& lhs, const SelfTracingAllocator<Id, U, BaseAlloc>& rhs)
{
    return true;
}

template<class T, class U, int Id, class BaseAlloc>
inline bool operator!=(const SelfTracingAllocator<Id, T, BaseAlloc>& lhs, const SelfTracingAllocator<Id, U, BaseAlloc>& rhs )
{
    return false;
}


template<class T, int Id>
struct my_allocator
{
    typedef SelfTracingAllocator<Id, T, some_allocator<T, MemMgr> > type;
};
```

When I use this allocator like below

```
typedef custom_string<wchar_t, char_traits<wchar_t>, my_allocator<int, 0>::type > string_t;
```

I get errors like below

```
error C2664: 'char_traits<T>::move' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int *' to 'wchar_t *'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=wchar_t
1>        ]
1>        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>        D:\VRS_Branch\detail/dynamic_buffer.hpp(95) : while compiling class template member function 'void detail::dynamic_buffer<T,Alloc,Traits>::reserve(unsigned int)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=wchar_t,
1>            Alloc=SelfTracingAllocator<0,int,some_allocator<int,MemMgr>>,
1>            Traits=char_traits<wchar_t>
1>        ]
```

Why does it happen? I have both rebind structure and rebinding copy constructor, so what goes wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Andriy

Comment: You should post minimal complete example.

Comment: Show the BaseAlloc code please. And i can't see you using T for SelfTracingAllocator.

Comment: What happens if you replace `base` by `BaseAlloc` in the rebind typedef?

Comment: Why are you writing an assignment operator? Not only does yours return the wrong type, but is it even necessary? Try removing it.

Comment: @Kerrek SB nothing changes when replacing with BaseAlloc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using

```
template<typename Other>
struct rebind
{
    typedef SelfTracingAllocator<
        Id
        , Other
        , typename base::template rebind<Other>::other
    > other;
};
```

?

Right now if you have a `SelfTracingAllocator<0, int, std::allocator<int> >` then rebinding to `wchar_t` will yield `SelfTracingAllocator<0, wchar_t, std::allocator<int> >`. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Nice catch! That looks very promising.

Comment: That's exactlY what I thought about after @GreenScape gave me a hint about using T in SelfTracingAllocator